# Typescript: Generic arguments as type value

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, constructor

I'm trying to perform some operations on a class' generic argument. Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
export type Constructable<TType> = new(...args: any[]) => TType;

export default class ThingDoer<TType> {
  public constructor(Type: Constructable<TType>) {
    this.thing = this.doTheThing(Type);
  }
}
```

But I have to pass the type by parameter and I'm trying to remove that parameter by doing something like this:

```
export default class ThingDoer<TType extends Constructable<TType>> {
  public constructor() {
    this.thing = this.doTheThing(TType);
  }
}
```

But it shows this error:

> 'TType' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Is there a way to skip passing the parameter to the constructor by doing something like this? Can a generic argument type be used as a parameter like regular types can?

Comment: What's the difference...? If it was allowed in some way, why would `new ThingDoer(Ctor)` be any different than `new ThingDoer<Ctor>()`? Also, no this is not possible.

Comment: No, this class is a base class of many others. That's not how I'm using it.

Comment: Oh ok, well then it's just plainly not possible. Currently, type reflection is very limited and is unable to do this either.

Comment: Damn. I was afraid that was the case.

Comment: You can only "pass" types via template arguments. Like this.doTheThing<T>(value: T). But even that's not really passing a type, you'll still have to discern it via the value.